# Looping a functions in init.d

Tags: arrays, bash, function, loops, init.d

I have an Init.d script that looks like this 
what I want to do is be able to start both data nodes  with one command -all unfortunately my scripts logic will only start one data node. basically my For-loop is only looping through one function. How can I ensure that both data nodes start when I enter all for the read statement?

```
  #!/bin/bash

# init.d / servicectl compatibility (openSUSE)
#
 if [ -f /etc/rc.status ]; then
. /etc/rc.status
rc_reset
fi

 if [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
 fi
#
 puppet(){
 ES_USER="kate"
ES_GROUP="kate"
 ES_HOME="/home/kate/test/puppet1/elasticsearch-5.6.12"
 MAX_OPEN_FILES=65536
MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144
LOG_DIR="/home/kate/test/puppet1/elasticsearch-5.6.12/logs"
DATA_DIR="/home/kate/test/puppet1/elasticsearch-5.6.12/data"
CONF_DIR="/home/kate/test/puppet1/elasticsearch-5.6.12/config"
PID_DIR="/home/kate/test/puppet1/elasticsearch-5.6.12/var"
 }
#master
master(){
ES_USER="kate"
ES_GROUP="kate"
ES_HOME="/home/kate/test/elasticsearch-5.6.12"
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65536
MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144
 LOG_DIR="/var/log/elasticsearch"
 DATA_DIR="/var/lib/elasticsearch"
 CONF_DIR="/home/kate/test/elasticsearch-5.6.12/config"
 PID_DIR="/var/run/elasticsearch"
 }


#created an array
declare -a functions=( master puppet  )

read a1
if [ "$a1" == "puppet" ]; then
puppet
elif [ "$a1" == "master" ]; then
master
fi
if [ "$a1" == "all" ]; then
  for i  in "${!functions[@]}" ;
 do
${functions[i]};
 done
fi
    ########### can pretty much ignore as this is as this is just what I want to run through ###########
   ES_ENV_FILE="/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch"
 if [ -f "$ES_ENV_FILE" ]; then . "$ES_ENV_FILE"
 fi

  if [ "$ES_USER" != "elasticsearch" ] || [ "$ES_GROUP" != "elasticsearch" 
]; then
   echo "WARNING: ES_USER and ES_GROUP are deprecated and will be removed in 
 the next major version of Elasticsearch, got: [$ES_USER:$ES_GROUP]"
fi
if [ ! -z "$CONF_FILE" ]; then
echo "CONF_FILE setting is no longer supported. elasticsearch.yml must be 
placed in the config directory and cannot be renamed."
exit 1
fi
 exec="$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch"
  prog="elasticsearch"
pidfile="$PID_DIR/${prog}.pid"
export ES_JAVA_OPTS
export JAVA_HOME
export ES_INCLUDE
export ES_JVM_OPTIONS
 export ES_STARTUP_SLEEP_TIME
if test -n "$ES_MIN_MEM"; then export ES_MIN_MEM; fi
if test -n "$ES_MAX_MEM"; then export ES_MAX_MEM; fi
 if test -n "$ES_HEAP_SIZE"; then export ES_HEAP_SIZE; fi
 if test -n "$ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE"; then export ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE; fi
if test -n "$ES_DIRECT_SIZE"; then export ES_DIRECT_SIZE; fi
if test -n "$ES_USE_IPV4"; then export ES_USE_IPV4; fi
 if test -n "$ES_GC_OPTS"; then export ES_GC_OPTS; fi
 if test -n "$ES_GC_LOG_FILE"; then export ES_GC_LOG_FILE; fi
 lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog
  if [ -n $USER ] && [ -z $ES_USER ] ; then
  ES_USER=$USER
   fi
   if [ ! -x "$exec" ]; then
  echo "The elasticsearch startup script does not exists or it is not 
executable, tried: $exec"
      exit 1
    fi
    checkJava() {
      if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
       JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
       else
       JAVA=`which java`
       fi
       if [ ! -x "$JAVA" ]; then
          echo "Could not find any executable java binary. Please install 
      java in 
      your PATH or set JAVA_HOME"
       exit 1
     fi
    }
   start() {
  checkJava
   [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
  if [ -n "$MAX_OPEN_FILES" ]; then
       ulimit -n $MAX_OPEN_FILES
  fi
  if [ -n "$MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY" ]; then
    ulimit -l $MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
  fi
  if [ -n "$MAX_MAP_COUNT" -a -f /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count ]; then
    sysctl -q -w vm.max_map_count=$MAX_MAP_COUNT
  fi
   if [ -n "$PID_DIR" ] && [ ! -e "$PID_DIR" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$PID_DIR" && chown "$ES_USER":"$ES_GROUP" "$PID_DIR"
   fi
   if [ -n "$pidfile" ] && [ ! -e "$pidfile" ]; then
    touch "$pidfile" && chown "$ES_USER":"$ES_GROUP" "$pidfile"
   fi
   cd $ES_HOME
   echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
   daemon --user $ES_USER --pidfile $pidfile $exec -p $pidfile -d - 
   Edefault.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Edefault.path.data=$DATA_DIR - 
   Edefault.path.conf=$CONF_DIR
    retval=$?
   echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
   }
   stop() {
     echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc -p $pidfile -d 86400 $prog
  retval=$?
  echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
   return $retval
   }
  restart() {
     stop
   start
 }

  reload() {
   restart
  }

    force_reload() {
   restart
  }
       rh_status() {
    status -p $pidfile $prog
   }

  rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
      }
    case "$1" in
 start)
    rh_status_q && exit 0
    $1
    ;;
stop)
    rh_status_q || exit 0
    $1
    ;;
restart)
    $1
    ;;
reload)
    rh_status_q || exit 7
    $1
    ;;
force-reload)
    force_reload
    ;;
status)
    rh_status
    ;;
condrestart|try-restart)
    rh_status_q || exit 0
    restart
    ;;
*)
     echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try- 
restart|reload|force-reload}"
    exit 2
esac
exit $?
```

Comment: Your `exit` statement is inside the `for` loop; it only iterates once. You appear to be missing a `done`, although it's not clear where it is suppose to go.

Comment: sorry I fixed the part I forgot to add which is just the done and fixed where the exit was sorry when i copied and pasted I had to do some manual config before posting made some errors.